# The code i written using importing numpy is giving errors

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

[this is the code but i am getting the error as you can see in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZgg8.jpg)

Code:
Import numpy 
Z=np.linspace(2,10,5)
Print(z)

I have also installed the numpy module in the virtual environment i am coding

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider to visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to check out how to ask good questions on SO.

Comment: please post code/text, not images. if the code is comprehensive, extract a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows: what do you want to do? what did you try? what goes wrong (actual vs. expected output)?

Answer (score 0):

you should make your module have a initial name like you have used it.
if you used initial `np` as your numpy module, you should make your module have a initial name.

> change : `import numpy` to `import numpy as np`.